# label under each subimage in the middle place (using includegraphics)

Tags: graphics, labels

I just wonder how can I have labels under each subimage and the label should be in the line under each image and in the **middle** place in accordance to each subimage in the next line. (I have 4 images in two rows.) Here is my code:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=1in]{box-eps-converted-to.pdf}
\includegraphics[width=1in]{ori_phantom_py-eps-converted-to.pdf} \\
\includegraphics[width=1in]{ct_thorax-eps-converted-to.pdf} 
\includegraphics[width=1in]{ct_chest-eps-converted-to.pdf}
\end{figure}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you could use the `subcaption` package

Comment: Are these labels to be referenceable, as in `\label` and `\ref`?  If not, then the `stackengine` package allows the letters to be conveniently stacked under the image, you specify the gap and alignment with respect to the figure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

with use of subcaptions as folllows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{1in}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{box-eps-converted-to.pdf}
    \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}\hfil
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{1in}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{ori_phantom_py-eps-converted-to.pdf} 
   \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}

    \begin{subfigure}[b]{1in}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{ct_thorax-eps-converted-to.pdf}
   \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}\hfil
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{1in}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{ct_chest-eps-converted-to.pdf}
   \caption{}
   \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the package subcaption. A very good description on how to use this if given on:

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions

It includes how to add both a caption and separate labels.

Comment: Please add an example of code to show your approach (its pretty standard of course), but we would appreciate you using our format.